# Python: iterate through two datetimes hourly

Tags: python, datetime

Here's the question:

Using python's datetime module, create an iterator that generates all the hours between two datetime.datatime objects.

`it = hourly_it( d1, d2)` # where `d1` and `d2` are `datetime.datetime` objects. 
For example,

```
from datetime import datetime
it = hourly_it( datetime(2018, 10, 2, 12), datetime(2018, 10, 3, 12))
```

will generates all the date times between 12:00 (noon) Novermber 2, to 12:00 (noon) November 3rd.

Here's my code:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta as td, datetime
   def hourly_it( d1, d2) :
      start = d1
      finish = d2
      def f():
         nonlocal start, finish
         if(start>=finish): return None
         start += td(hours=1)
         return start   
      return f
```

when I test the code using:

```
from datetime import datetime
  it = hourly_it( datetime(2018, 10, 2, 12), datetime(2018, 10, 3,12))
  print(next(it))
```

I get this error:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>
> in ()
>         1 from datetime import datetime
>         2 it = hourly_it( datetime(2018, 10, 2, 12), datetime(2018, 10, 3, 12))
>
> ----> 3 print(next(it))
>
> TypeError: 'function' object is not an iterator

I figured it out. Thanks all. Here is how you do it without using the generator. I should also note that I put the +1hour before the return and set the start >=

```
from datetime import date, timedelta as td, datetime
  def hourly_it( d1, d2) :
     start = d1
     finish = d2
     def f():
          nonlocal start, finish
          if(start>=finish): return None
          start += td(hours=1)
          return start

      return iter(f,None)
```

Comment: your indentation is not quite right. can you clean up the code your posted please.

Comment: Your indentation is still wrong

Comment: fixed again. thanks.

Comment: what happens in the case where there are more than 24 hours between the two dates? Should the hours reset or should they keep counting beyond 25?

Comment: I should be able to get a datetime for every hour. The 25th datestamp would be for the next day for example.

Answer (score 5):

I'm almost sure this is school work you got there.

But I'll give you some reading on python's iterator protocol, and short and sweet example maybe you get it; and its not rocket science anyway.

[The Iterator Protocol: How “For Loops” Work in Python](https://treyhunner.com/2016/12/python-iterator-protocol-how-for-loops-work/)

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> def hourly_it(start, finish):
...     while finish > start:
...             start = start + timedelta(hours=1)
...             yield start
>>> start = datetime(2018, 10, 2, 12)
>>> finish = datetime(2018, 10, 3, 12)
>>> for hour in hourly_it(start, finish):
...     print(hour)
...
2018-10-02 13:00:00
2018-10-02 14:00:00
2018-10-02 15:00:00
2018-10-02 16:00:00
2018-10-02 17:00:00
2018-10-02 18:00:00
2018-10-02 19:00:00
2018-10-02 20:00:00
2018-10-02 21:00:00
2018-10-02 22:00:00
2018-10-02 23:00:00
2018-10-03 00:00:00
2018-10-03 01:00:00
2018-10-03 02:00:00
2018-10-03 03:00:00
2018-10-03 04:00:00
2018-10-03 05:00:00
2018-10-03 06:00:00
2018-10-03 07:00:00
2018-10-03 08:00:00
2018-10-03 09:00:00
2018-10-03 10:00:00
2018-10-03 11:00:00
2018-10-03 12:00:00
```

Comment: The yield statement should happen before you add the hour; otherwise, this has the possibility of returning a time past the finish datetime, since the `while` check happens before the hour is added.

Comment: yeah, go figure by 'the hours between the two dates'... that is just my way of explaining python's iterator protocol to him. He can still do the homework. I could do the other way around (yield first), and you'll still be able to point the same thing the other way around, so I just didn't bother

Comment: @PedroRodrigues. Problem is, that statement uses a generator which I also had to solve in the next question (yes it's homework).                               
from datetime import date, timedelta as td, datetime
def hourly_gen( d1, d2) :
    while(d1<=d2):
        yield d1       
        d1 = d1 + td(hours=1)

Comment: At least you openly assume its homework. I won't be touching the code, has you might have guessed already. The iterator protocol is clearly demonstrated, the decision of using your example (or what I understood from your question) is simply a kind one and any other example would be as good or better to achieve what I was looking for, demonstrating the iterator protocol. There is nothing wrong with bringing homework to stack overflow, just give your try, expose your doubts, and be clear it is homework, but don't expect people to do it for you you'll be very lucky if that happens.

Comment: If there is a specific doubt you have in code, go ahead, I'll clarify whatever needs clarification.